# dependencyManagement unfortunately not transitive

Tags: maven, dependency-management

Recently, I keep running into the following problem:

Library project A has a transitive dependency B. The dependency B has vulnerabilities. I correct this by adding a `<dependencyManagement>` entry to A (or its multi-module parent) that updates B. Then everything is fine, dependency tree and dependency list are good, tests are green.

Now some other project P uses A as dependency. In project P, the transitive dependency B again has the bad (vulnerable) version because `<dependencyManagement>` of A is ignored.

What shall I do

- add the `<dependencyManagement>` entry also to P, although it does not really belong there?
- do not use `<dependencyManagement>`, but just dependencies?

Comment: It would be great if some of the close voters would explain why this is "opinion based". Especially since there is already a really good answer below (which is also accepted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are another two options for completeness:

1. `flatten-maven-plugin` has [a setting](https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/flatten-mojo.html#flattenDependencyMode) allowing to overcome such issue:

> Flatten both direct and transitive dependencies. This will examine the full dependency tree, and pull up all transitive dependencies as a direct dependency, and setting their versions appropriately.
> **This is recommended if you are releasing a library that uses dependency management to manage dependency versions**.

However it generates weird poms like:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.23</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.23</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
```

2. It seems everything was already implemented in `maven-resolver` project but wasn't integrated into maven (please check [MNG-5761](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5761), [MRESOLVER-10](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOLVER-10), [MRESOLVER-33](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOLVER-33)). From that perspective it seems to be enough to implement trivial extension like:

```java
import org.apache.maven.AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant;
import org.apache.maven.MavenExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession;
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.annotations.Component;
import org.eclipse.aether.DefaultRepositorySystemSession;
import org.eclipse.aether.util.graph.manager.DefaultDependencyManager;

@Component(role = AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant.class)
public class TransitiveDependencyManagementLifecycleParticipant extends AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant {

    @Override
    public void afterSessionStart(MavenSession session) throws MavenExecutionException {
        ((DefaultRepositorySystemSession) session.getRepositorySession())
                .setDependencyManager(new DefaultDependencyManager());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your deep knowledge. I did not notice number 1 and I would never have thought of number 2.