Example of transitive dependency resolution with dependencyManagement?
In the docs, it states:

Dependency management - this allows project authors to directly specify the versions of artifacts to be used when they are encountered in transitive dependencies or in dependencies where no version has been specified. In the example in the preceding section a dependency was directly added to A even though it is not directly used by A. Instead, A can include D as a dependency in its dependencyManagement section and directly control which version of D is used when, or if, it is ever referenced.

However, based on the answer and follow-up comments in this question, I'm even more conflicted.
Put simply, if A depends on B, and B depends on C v1.0, and I declare in <dependencyManagement> for A a version for C, v2.0, what do I expect about what version A pulls in for C? Is it 1.0 or 2.0? Do I have to add this to <dependencies> as stated in the answer (even though the comment says the answer is out of date)?
I'd just like a simple example to illustrate what I should expect in terms of transitive dependency management as outlined above, and an answer relevant to Maven v3.9.0. Thanks in advance!

*Management sections are fundamentally broken in maven: if you are an application (war, spring-boot, etc) you will fine with them, however, if you are a library the consumer of your library will pull "undesired" versions of transitive dependencies.

@AndreyB.Panfilov Can you source more what you're affirming? I'm using dependencies management in Maven for long, without notable troubles

yup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75510285/dependencymanagement-unfortunately-not-transitive

thoughts on plugin management

Please show an real example pom for that...
